# Cannot catch `FacebookAuthenticationException`, but other exceptions are fine

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to access the facebook API. When I use an expired page access token, the API throws `\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException`, and I am supposed to fetch a new one. However, I am not able to catch this exception, only the more generic `FacebookSDKException`:

```
<?php
namespace my\company;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '<app_id>',
    'app_secret' => '<app_secret>',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v5.0',
]);

$access_token = '<access token>';
$query = '/mypage/feed?message,id';
try {
    $response = $fb->get($query, $access_token);
}
catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException $e) {
    // handle it
}
```

This fails with:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException: Error validating access token: Session has expired on Sunday, 19-Jan-20 09:00:00 PST. The current time is Saturday, 25-Jan-20 06:07:17 PST. in C:\myproject\wp-content\plugins\someplugin\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException.php:89 Stack trace:
#0 C:\myproject\wp-content\plugins\someplugin\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse.php(210): Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::create(Object(Facebook\FacebookResponse))
#1 C:\myproject\wp-content\plugins\someplugin\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse.php(255): Facebook\FacebookResponse->makeException()
#2 C:\myproject\wp-content\plugins\someplugin\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\FacebookResponse.php(82): Facebook\FacebookResponse->decodeBody()
#3 C:\myproject\wp-content\plugins\someplugin\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\FacebookClient.php(224) in C:\myproject\wp-content\plugins\someplugin\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException.php on line 89
```

However, I can catch `\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException` or `\Exception` fine, as opposed to in this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778839/i-cant-catch-facebookexceptions-in-try-catch-block)! The solution reccommended there also does not work. I tried adding `use Facebook`, `use \Facebook`, and multiple variations of initial backslashes or not, but I still can't catch that specific exception. Is there anything that could cause this?